# Cassandra multi data centre cluster configuration

Tags: cassandra

We are decided to use "cassandra" as a database and now want to go with cluster with two datacenters DC1 & DC2. This DC2 is for backup purpose and it is replica of DC1.
Initially we are expecting the data size going to save into db is about 2 Terabyte and this size grows eventually.

As I am new to cassandra, I need some help here in getting the estimate for server/node configurations for this cluster like

- how many nodes are enough handle this data. Its' cpu configurations like RAM, ROM and number of cpu cores

It would be grateful if someone can help me with atleast rough estimations.

Note : We are going with opensource cassandra of 3.11 version